# Is there a command line or programmatic way to add an indicator/script to a chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a command line or programmatic way to add an indicator/script to a chart ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can add it from the *Indicators* tab or *Pine Editor*.

[image]